# Sobolev space extension operator

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $1\leq p\leq\infty$. There exists a bounded linear operator $P:W^{1,\,p}(I)\rightarrow W^{1,\,p}(\mathbb{R})$, called an extension operator, satisfying the following properties:

(i) $Pu|_{I}=u\quad\forall u\in W^{1,\,p}(I)$,

(ii) $\|Pu\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})}\leq C\|u\|_{L^{p}(I)}\quad\forall u\in W^{1,\,p}(I)$,

(iii) $\|Pu\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})}\leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,\,p}(I)}\quad\forall u\in W^{1,\,p}(I)$,

where $C$ depends only on $|I|\leq\infty$.

I understand the majority of the proof except for finding the constants $C$. The proof goes as follows:

Let $I=(0,1)$ we show that extension by reflection,
\begin{align}
(Pu)(x)=u^{*}(x)=\begin{cases}
u(x)\quad &x\geq 0\\
u(-x)\quad &x<0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
works. We have,
\begin{align}
\|u^{*}\|_{p}^{p}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u^{*}|^{p}dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}|u^{*}|^{p}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}|u^{*}|^{p}dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}|u(-x)|^{p}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^{p}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^{p}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^{p}dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^{p}dx=2\|u\|_{p}^{p},
\end{align}
which implies $\|u^{*}\|_{p}\leq 2^{1/p}\|u\|_{p}$.

However something must be going wrong with my working because the correct inequality is $\|u^{*}\|_{p}\leq 2\|u\|_{p}$. Can anyone identify where I am going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You have $2^{1/p} \le 2$ for $p \in [1,\infty]$ and this bound $2$ is independent of $p$.

Comment: This is a face palm moment. Thank you.